# Model filed values are not updating in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

Am building this voting platform, users will have to but the votes. They will input the number of votes to they want to buy, then make payment. After a successful payment, The number of votes they just bought should be added to their old votes in the database.

For instance, say a user buys 2 votes at a price of 10USD and have 3 votes already, the 2 should should be added to the 3 to make it 5.

My problem is 10USD is rather added to the users votes.

```
models.py

class Nomination(models.Model):
    Fullname = models.CharField(max_length=120)
    Nominee_ID = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    Category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='nominations_images')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150)
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Fullname
```

```
views.py

def nomination_payView(request, slug):
        if request.method == 'GET':
            model = get_object_or_404(Nomination, slug=slug)
            template_name = 'Payment.html'
            context = {
                'nomination': model
            }
            return render(request, 'Payment.html', context)
        elif request.method == 'POST':
            amount = (str(int(request.POST['votes']) * float(request.POST['price'])) + '0').replace('.', '')
            zeros = '0' * (12 - len(amount))
            amount = zeros + amount
            email = request.POST['email']

            url = 'https://test.theteller.net/checkout/initiate'
            transaction_id = random.randint(100000000000, 999999999999)
            data = {
                "merchant_id": "TTM-00000740",
                "transaction_id": transaction_id,
                "desc": "Payment Using Checkout Page",
                "amount": amount,
                "redirect_url": f"http://127.0.0.1:8000/process-payment/{slug}/{amount}",
                "email": email,
                "API_Key": "ZDQ2OGEyZDNjN2YzMDY5ZDVkY2MyM2U5YTRiMGI0N2Q=",
                "apiuser": "halotech5d525bfd6ead3",
            
            }
            encoded = base64.b64encode(
                b'halotech5d525bfd6ead3:ZDQ2OGEyZDNjN2YzMDY5ZDVkY2MyM2U5YTRiMGI0N2Q=')
            headers = {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                'Authorization': f'Basic {encoded.decode("utf-8")}',
                'Cache-Control': 'no-cache'
            }
            res = requests.post(url, data=json.dumps(data), 
            headers=headers).json()
            print(res['checkout_url'])
            return redirect(res["checkout_url"])

def process_payment(request, slug, amount):
    trans_id = request.GET.get('transaction_id')
    status = request.GET.get('status')
    reason = request.GET.get('reason')
    transaction_id = request.GET.get('transaction_id')
    if status == 'Approved':
        transaction = SuccessfulTransactionHistory(
            nominee_name=slug,
            transaction_id=transaction_id,
            amount=amount
        )
        transaction.save()
        nomination = Nomination.objects.filter(slug=slug).values('votes')
        Nomination.objects.filter(slug=slug).update(votes=int(nomination[0]['votes']) + int(amount[:-2]))
        return redirect('/success')
    else:
        context = {
            'error': reason
        }
        transaction = FailedTransactionHistory(
            nominee_name=slug,
            transaction_id=transaction_id,
            amount=amount
        )
        transaction.save()
        return render(request, 'payment_error.html', context=context)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need to perform separate queries to get the value (first) and then to increment (second). Just use an [F expression](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions) to access a field from the same model and perform an increment in a single operation:

```
from django.db.models import F

Nomination.objects.filter(slug=slug).update(votes=F('votes') + amount)
```

No need to cast `Nomination.votes` to `int` because it already is. But if `amount` is an `str` (though better if you accept it in your URL as an `int` to avoid conversions such as this):

```
Nomination.objects.filter(slug=slug).update(votes=F('votes') + int(amount[:-2]))  # The slice [:-2] was used as performed in the question. Adjust accordingly depending on what the amount really contains.
```

Here, all `Nomination` objects with the target `slug` would have their `votes` incremented by the said amount.

---

**Update**

Since we need the count of `votes`, we should not just accept the `amount` here since it is already the product of `votes * price`. What we can do is change the call to this API and include `votes` by changing `nomination_payView()` specifically this line:

```
"redirect_url": f"http://127.0.0.1:8000/process-payment/{slug}/{amount}",
```

To something like:

```
"redirect_url": f"http://127.0.0.1:8000/process-payment/{slug}/{amount}?votes={request.POST['votes']}",
```

Or:

```
"redirect_url": f"http://127.0.0.1:8000/process-payment/{slug}/{amount}/{request.POST['votes']}",
```

- What you would choose depends on what is possible to be processed by the endpoint `https://test.theteller.net/checkout/initiate` as it will do the redirect.

Then within this `process_payment` API, we can simply access that count directly from the query parameters:

```
Nomination.objects.filter(slug=slug).update(votes=F('votes') + int(request.GET['votes']))
```

Or if you chose the 2nd option from path parameters

```
Nomination.objects.filter(slug=slug).update(votes=F('votes') + votes)  # Assuming you defined the URL as something like <path("process-payment/{str:slug}/{int:amount}/{int:votes}", ...> and the view function as <def process_payment(request, slug, amount, votes):>
```

Comment: The update happens but the price of the votes added instead of the number of votes. I have updated my question and provided the payment view as.

Comment: The field `Nomination.votes` is the number of votes right? Or is it the price of votes? Also what is the sample value of amount, is it a price or the number of votes?

Comment: Amount is the number of votes bought. I just updated the question with my payment views as well. kindly check @Niel Godfrey Ponciano

Comment: Within `nomination_payView`, you are only passing the amount e.g. `10` which is already the product of votes `2` and price `5`. We can't guess the number of votes from the amount because it could be the result of 2*5, or 5*2, or 1*10, or 10*1, and so on. Or is price fixed at the rate of `5`? You should change the call to forward the votes and the price individually, not as amount. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes the price is fixed at 0.5.  Can you change the call to forward the votes and prices individually for me or any better way to get it done.  Am stacked here please.  @Niel Godfrey Ponciano

Comment: We may change the processing made within `https://test.theteller.net/checkout/initiate` to accept and forward votes and price instead of just amount but I'm not sure if it's possible as it seems external. For the meantime while that is not possible and while the price is fixed at `5`, just change it to `Nomination.objects.filter(slug=slug).update(votes=F('votes') + (int(amount) // 5))`. Could you try this?

Comment: @spiritman I know now a better solution for your problem, please check my updated answer.

Comment: I another problem is occurring at `if status == 'Approved':` its not making the successful vote to be saved and counted. This is the response from the API. Any suggestions?     /process-payment/robert-yenji/000000000050/votes=1status=Approved&code=000&reason=Approved%3A%20Transaction%20successful!&transaction_id=664983350206

Comment: What successful vote? I think we are drifting away now from the original question. The problem in the original question is only that votes isn't updated, now it is :) We actually already solved another problem which is that `amount` isn't actually the votes. That one is another problem. I think we can move on to another question for that different topic. If my post answers the original problem, you might want to accept it as the answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers and let's move to your next question differently.

Comment: @ Niel Godfrey Poncianookay.  Thank you. i have accepted this one. Kindly take a look at the new question here for me please:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69303884/i-cant-filter-get-data-from-my-url-to-save-into