# I can't filter get data from my url to save into

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I want to save transaction and increase the number of votes base on the status which i get from a response url nd redirect user to success page. But all transactions goes to error page rather even if they are successful.

I want to check from the URL if the `status== 'Approved'`  then i save the model and update the the model with new votes and redirect user to success page. this is the url response i get    `http://127.0.0.1:8000/process-payment/robert-yenji/000000000050/?votes=1?status=Approved&code=000&reason=Approved%3A%20Transaction%20successful!&transaction_id=314304818998`

this is

```
 my views.py


def process_payment(request, slug, amount):
    trans_id = request.GET.get('transaction_id')
    status = request.GET.get('status')
    reason = request.GET.get('reason')
    transaction_id = request.GET.get('transaction_id')
    if status == 'Approved':
        transaction = SuccessfulTransactionHistory(
            nominee_name=slug,
            transaction_id=transaction_id,
            amount=amount
        )
        transaction.save()
        nomination = Nomination.objects.filter(slug=slug).values('votes')
        Nomination.objects.filter(slug=slug).update(votes=F('votes') + int(request.GET['votes']))
        return redirect('/success')
    else:
        context = {
            'error': reason
        }
        transaction = FailedTransactionHistory(
            nominee_name=slug,
            transaction_id=transaction_id,
            amount=amount
        )
        transaction.save()
        return render(request, 'payment_error.html', context=context)
```

Comment: It seems that the format of the query parameters is incorrect specifically this part `/?votes=1?status=Approved&` as it should be `/?votes=1&status=Approved&` (2nd `?` replaced by `&`). Try checking if `request.GET` contains both query params. Can this be corrected? If not, then I think as discussed in the other [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69298441/model-filed-values-are-not-updating-in-django/69298568?noredirect=1#comment122492247_69298568), we might need to change `votes` to be a path parameter `.../{votes}/?...` instead of a query parameter `.../?votes={votes}...`.

Comment: worked!. thanks @Niel Godfrey Ponciano